# Move rectangle inside PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, mouse, picturebox, move, rectangles

I have an PictureBox for image, when the image is loaded a draw a rectangle into middle of the PictureBox. Rectangle is hardcoded into default position and I want users to move it and place in over the desired area of the image.

Any ideas how to move rectangle inside PictureBox using just mouse/keyboard?

Comment: So far, I have tried to search SO, but with no results. I need users to be able to drag the rectangle a move it.

Comment: Very unclear what the hangup could be.  Just change the Rectangle variable with the MouseMove event and call the pbox' Invalidate() method to get it repainted.

Comment: Thank you Hans, Invalidate() should do the work. Now I just need to use right PictureBox events for the action to be intuitive for users ;).